# pc to pc via bluetooth using bluecove

Tags: java, bluetooth, bluecove

There is plenty of examples on the internet showing how to write an app that allows us to e.g. communicate pc from a mobile phone via bluetooth. But what I am trying to do is to control one pc from another pc via bluetooth. I am trying to use bluetooth library. I run the server on one pc and try to connect from another one by using examples from here: http://bluecove.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/bluecove/src/test/java/com/intel/bluetooth/javadoc/

It finds the device:

```
Device BC7737946D89 found
     name TN-RR-LAP
Device Inquiry completed!
search services on BC7737946D89 TN-RR-LAP
service search completed!
```

But then it tries to connect and I am getting the following error:

```
Connecting to btspp://BC7737946D89:9;authenticate=false;encrypt=false;master=false
Exception in thread "main" javax.bluetooth.BluetoothConnectionException: Failed to connect; [10064] A socket operation failed because the destination host was down.
    at com.intel.bluetooth.BluetoothStackMicrosoft.connect(Native Method)
BlueCove stack shutdown completed
    at com.intel.bluetooth.BluetoothStackMicrosoft.access$700(BluetoothStackMicrosoft.java:44)
    at com.intel.bluetooth.BluetoothStackMicrosoft$ConnectThread.run(BluetoothStackMicrosoft.java:651)
Java Result: 1
```

Anybody knows how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to transfer from PC to PC i suggest using btgoep://bluetoothaddress:2 and it should work.